# How can I configure the record type of DigitalOcean for working with DirectAdmin?

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, directadmin

1. I want to know the DNS configuration of DigitalOcean for working with DirectAdmin.
2. I want to create own Name Server on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create your private nameserver with ns1 and ns2.domainname with your VM IP and register that at your domain registrar panel with VM IP.